# how to represent a long string of different size according to screen size in xamarin android?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin

I am developing an android application in xamarin using C#. I have a long string (of chapter content) on a textview.
Currently I am using scroll view to show the content on a text view.
How should I manage (e.g. via pagination) to fit the string in a textlayout? How can I know how many characters can fit in different mobiles' screens?

Comment: You can use the ViewPager.

Comment: Tried to make readable. Some of your existing code would help here.

Answer (score 0):

Create  dimens.xml file in values folder with proper qualifier like  values-mdpi,values-ldpi,values-sw720dp,values-sw600dp and more ...

just explore where you can put these files in Xamarin project

For Example 
**values-ldpi folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <dimen name="text_size">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

just modify according to your needs.